# Keep a single document in mongoDB collection using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I created a collection but that one should keep a single document inside.
How do I ensure that there is a single document in mongoose schema?

Answer (score 6):

You can create "capped" collections, where you can set limit of documents, you can store in it.

It does not however prevent adding another document (not sure, if you need that functionality) - if you add another document, the old one would be deleted.

```
db.createCollection('mycappedcol',{capped: true, size:999999, max:1})
```

Also you cant delete documents from capped collections, you can only replace them with new ones or drop the whole collection.

PS : In capped collections, you have to specify size in bytes, which is also a limit (collection cant be bigger than specified size). If you do not care about size, but you care only about limit, just set size big enough.

Comment: Don't set the size too high: "When creating a capped collection you must specify the maximum size of the collection in bytes, which MongoDB will pre-allocate for the collection"