# How to store application configuration in Mongodb/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I have an application server running on Ruby/rails and mongodb/mopngoid for data persistence. My application server has some confifguration parameters which are configurable: for instances the timezone, financial year start, base currency, amount of records to show per table, etc.... What is the best way to store these configuration data (in mongodb)? I can create a model in mongodb with all these parameter and store it in a collection where I always use the first record. But is there a better way to store a single document? I read about capped collections but not sure this is again a twist?

Rgds
Michael

Comment: As with any configuration, you can add a setting attribute to your User model (or any) and provide a default configuration for each user and allow each instance/user to change their individual settings. JSON is perfect for this use case

Comment: Hi, yep - this is what I am doing for all my user related configuration. But I also have globale configuration parameter for my application server - like for example a mail server configuration. Or the company name, ... these configuration parameter are global and do not vary by users.

Comment: Why not use a YML file with a few environmental variables.

Comment: Hi, the parameter shall still be configurable during runtime. And since I already use mongodb for data persistence and have the framework, screen setup etc to interface with mongo DB I was hoping to find an easy way with mongodb. There is already a solution - just use one collection with a single document. But doesn't sound right.

Comment: I think you should be fine with capped collections like you already suggested initially. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868691/keep-a-single-document-in-mongodb-collection-using-mongoose . Which addresses the same problem, also you can read more about capped collections here 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/